# how to inject javascript without using script tags?

Tags: javascript, xss

I cant use the script tags
It alerts when I do , which is only useful for testing.
It filters them out:

```
    script > *
    SCRIPT > SCRIPT
    sCriPt > sCriPt
```

so, i try to use capital script tags
but it turns to:

```
    *CRIPT>alert(1)</SCRIPT>
```

I have tried using multiple tags.

How can I inject regular javascript with this?
Oh, and I cant use quotes.

Comment: What's the context? Inject JavaScript where?

Comment: In a post field. its persistent

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hacking

Comment: this is a challenge my co worker setup on his site.

Comment: @user2318029 You already have the cheat sheet and that has a huge list of things you can try to post, if the site does it's checking with JavaScript then try to re create the form and submit it without executing the JavaScript (some very complicated validation and filtering are sometimes only done in JavaScript). It's better not to allow any user to post HTML and use tags in text like Stack overflow does. If you look at the cheat sheet I'm sure that with enough time you'll find a way to inject script in your posted content.

Comment: It's quite unfortunate this question was closed as I have the same question. I'd like to load javascript into a browser without the script tag. It's quite easy to figure out the context by use of the word script as that's an HTML tag. This has nothing to do with cross site script loading. Maybe the poster wants to use it for nefarious reasons, perhaps not. AMD loaders that don't use the script tag is not unreasonable. I'm ashamed at the community regarding this post.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter You only interpreted it as hacking. It frustrates me when the community acts like this and is why I'm not more active in it. I was lead to this post because I am trying to PROTECT my site from having this happen to it. I am filtering out script tags but was informed there are other ways to inject script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so you know, there is an [XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) you can refer to.

Comment: couldnt find anything useful, already tried encoding

Comment: Mind to share it?